# this.state.elements.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to enter to values in a textbox and print them on button click by setting react state. I am pushing object in array initialized in a state the value of text boxes is pushing but not getting mapped. it giving error this.state.elements.map is not a function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {
       elements: [
        {element1 :"A",element2: "A"},
        {element1 :"B",element2: "B"},
        {element1 :"C",element2: "C"},
        {element1 :"D",element2: "D"}

       ],
    }
    this.elementInput = "";
    this.elementInput_2 = "";

}
addItems()
  {
    debugger
    this.setState({
     elements : this.state.elements.push({
       element1 : this.elementInput.value ,
       element2 : this.elementInput_2.value
     })

   })
   console.log()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Element" ref={(input) => this.elementInput = input} />
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Element" ref={(input) => this.elementInput_2 = input} />
       <button onClick={this.addItems.bind(this)}>Add</button>
       {
          this.state.elements.map((item,index)=> {
            return  <p key={index}>{item.element1 + " " + item.element2}</p>
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can use `.concat()` instead of `.push()`; it returns the new array. Anyway, the most important thing here is to understand that the error means that `this.state.elements` is no longer an Array, and to debug it, you need to find the line that causes this. If you don't learn how to read error messages, you'll keep getting stuck like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
this.state.elements.push({
    element1 : this.elementInput.value ,
    element2 : this.elementInput_2.value
})
```

to

```
[...this.state.elements, {
    element1 : this.elementInput.value ,
    element2 : this.elementInput_2.value
}]
```

In your `addItems` code, you're assigning the output of [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to `elements`. It returns the `length` of the new array, not the new array.

As rightly mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034483/this-state-elements-map-is-not-a-function/54034561?noredirect=1#comment94904680_54034561) below, if you need to access previous state, is recommended to use the callback way of setting state, like

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  elements: [
    ...prevState.elements,
    {
      /* New object */
    }
  ]
}));
```

Comment: Use setState with callback and prevState when you want to access previous state elements

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here when you set state

```
this.setState({
    elements : this.state.elements.concat([{
      element1 : this.elementInput.value ,
      element2 : this.elementInput_2.value
    }])
  })
```

`push` returns the new length of the array, so `state.elements` is no longer an array.

You can use spread to do this instead. I also used the callback pattern to use previous state.

```
this.setState(st => {
    return {
      elements : [  
        ...st.elements, 
        {
          element1 : this.elementInput.value ,
          element2 : this.elementInput_2.value
        }
      ]  
    }
  })
```

Another way is using `concat`

```
elements : st.elements.concat(
     {
       element1 : this.elementInput.value ,
       element2 : this.elementInput_2.value
     }))
```

Comment: push returns the element that is being pushed, no it's the next length of the array

Comment: ah yea thanks for correcting me on that!

Answer (score 0):

Here you mutate the reference of `this.state.elements` with the function `push` and it's return the next length of the array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

To solve your problem you can use concat function:

```
addItems() {     
  this.setState({
    elements : this.state.elements.concat([{
      element1 : this.elementInput.value ,
      element2 : this.elementInput_2.value
    }])
  })
}
```